# pandoc: customize tabular conversion in rst

Tags: pandoc, restructured-text

Consider the following `mwe`

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{mylabel}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        1 & 2\\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When converting the file to `rst` using the following command

```
pandoc -o mwe.rst mwe.tex
```

then I receive the following

### mwe.rst

```
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   |
+-----+-----+
| 3   | 4   |
+-----+-----+

Table: my caption
```

However, I would like the output to be

```
.. _mylabel:

.. table:: my caption

   +-----+-----+
   | 1   | 2   |
   +-----+-----+
   | 3   | 4   |
   +-----+-----+
```

which does three things: it gives the table a number,it gives the table a caption, and it allows the table to be referenced.

How can I tweak `pandoc` to output the `tabular` in my desired format?

Comment: I'm using the following, in the mean time: `perl -p0i -e 's|(\.\. _tab.*?$)(.*?)^Table:(.*?)$|my $label=$1; my $body=$2; my $caption=$3; $body=~s/^/\t/mg; $label."\n\n.. table:: ".$caption."\n\n".$body;|msge' mwe.rst
`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not providing the output format to pandoc, and so it is outputting markdown rather than RST:

```
$ pandoc -o mwe.rst mwe.tex -f latex -t rst
```

should give:

```
.. table:: my caption

   +-----+-----+
   | 1   | 2   |
   +-----+-----+
   | 3   | 4   |
   +-----+-----+
```

Secondly, unfotunately pandoc does not inherently have a concept of table labels.
So when it reads in the table, it ignores the label.

The best route would be to create a pandoc filter. Using [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/) is a nice approach.

```
>> import panflute as pf
>> content = pf.convert_text(tex, input_format="latex")
>> content
[Table(TableRow(TableCell(Plain(Str(1))) TableCell(Plain(Str(2)))) TableRow(TableCell(Plain(Str(3))) TableCell(Plain(Str(4)))); alignment=['AlignLeft', 'AlignCenter'], width=[0, 0], rows=2, cols=2)]
>> content.insert(0, pf.RawBlock(".. _mylabel:", format="rst"))
...
```